# How to add a reply button in telegram message?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

How to add a button below the message in telegram using bot with php so that if someone click on that button it send some text to that chat id
[See the image for more clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhBwI.png)

I am able to send reply_markup keyboard but not able to send attached button as shown in figure. According to image if someone click on "show me right answer" button it send to that chat the right answer.

```
$replyMarkup = array(
'keyboard' => array(
    array("A", "B")
    )
);
    $encodedMarkup = json_encode($replyMarkup);

file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".$msg."&parse_mode=Markdown"."&reply_markup=".$encodedMarkup);
```

Comment: It's called a callback button/query: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery